# Div element takes all width when other element disappear

Tags: html, css

I created two DIV elements. Those **two DIV elements** will be only in one page, and in all other pages will be only **one DIV element**.
When second element disappear, first element automatically takes all width.
Sorry, i can't add pictures yet, but i will try to create an example:

> [div element "one"] width:50% [div element "two"] width:50%

*div element "two" disappear

> [div element"one"] width 100%

How can i get like that? With simple CSS/HTML i can't reach result like in an image.
* And I cant change class of DIV element

Comment: A quick and dirty hack would be to include a stylesheet on the page with the 2 divs, and apply your width:50% there

Comment: Perhaps a link would work just as well as a picture. Could you use a class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="two">two</div>
<div class="one">one</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.two{
    background:red;
    float:right;
    width:50%;
}
.one{
    background:green;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/gJ22P/

**OR**

You can use **display:table** property for this.

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/gJ22P/1/

It's work's till IE8 & above.

Comment: Nice one. Would have thought that content from "two" is "above" the first div. But works perfectly.

Comment: IF you don't want to change your mark up then you can use display:table property for this. Check this http://jsfiddle.net/gJ22P/1/ . It's work till IE8 & above .

Answer (score 2):

You could style your div depending on the parent container class:

Page 1:

```
<body class="twocolumn">
  <div id="div1">foo</div>
  <div id="div2">bar</div>
</body>
```

Page 2:

```
<body class="singlecolumn">
  <div id="div1">foo</div>
</body>
```

css file:

```
.twocolumn #div1 { width: 50%; }
.singlecolumn #div1 { width: 100%; }
#div2 {width: 50%; }
```

Comment: Thanks for help, but i can't change parent classes, that's the problem.

Comment: Thanks, it's not mine ;) I think wordpress uses this method in a lot of themes.

Comment: @Arnolds: What *can* you change?

Comment: Well, those two `div`s aren't won't even be on the same "line". I think the OP forgot to mention that he's using `display: inline-block;` or somesuch.

Comment: Sorry, probably i explaned my problem bad. Those two div's are on same line.